# Cordova project not working on Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, cordova, mac-catalyst

When I build a cordova project on Mac Catalyst on Xcode it gives me this error:

`Myapp.app: unsealed contents present in the bundle root Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`

What can I do?